# MainActivity for Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova

How does one go about establishing the class name for the MainActivity in a Cordova/Phonegap hybrid app?  I have tried

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ActivityInfo[] activities = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;
```

and then attempted to retrieve the main activity name as `activities[0].name` which simply returns `MainActivity` but then latter `Class.forName()` with this name throws an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make use of `getLaunchIntentForPackage` to get this info. The sample code is as follows:

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
String className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
```

Hope it helps.